# GAE transactions: pass entity or key?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

When doing a transaction with GAE, it is ok to pass the entity or should you pass always pass the key to the entity.  For example, suppose I'm transferring money from one entity to another.  Should I do this:

```
@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def transfer_money(key1, key2, amount):
    entity1 = key1.get()
    entity2 = key2.get()
    entity1.money -= amount
    entity2.money += amount
    ndb.put_multi([entity1, entity2])
```

or is this ok:

```
@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def transfer_money(entity1, entity2, amount):
    entity1.money -= amount
    entity2.money += amount
    ndb.put_multi([entity1, entity2])
```

Or does it depend on other factors?

Comment: entities can go up to a full meg, so at a point, it could become simply, easier, to just pass a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example does not produce the desired result. The entities are retrieved outside the transaction, so `money` on either may have changed already before it is written back and might be overwritten with a wrong value.

This particular case is also a good example to use [tasklets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#tasklets).

```
@ndb.transactional_tasklet(xg=True)
def transfer_money(key1, key2, amount):
    entity1, entity2 = yield key1.get_async(), key2.get_async() # parallel
    entity1.money -= amount
    entity2.money += amount
    yield entity1.put_async(), entity2.put_async() # parallel

transfer_money(key1, key2, amount).check_success()
```

This is faster and more efficient than using `get` or `put` in serial, or their `multi` variants.

Comment: Thanks, great answer.  I've been meaning to learn about tasklets.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK #2 does not work (transactionally), you need to load (and put) the objects inside the transaction.